# Why do I get "XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode" when I try to install Digest::SHA?

Tags: perl, unix, 32bit-64bit, aix

I am trying to install [Digest::SHA](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::SHA) v5.95, but I get the following error:

> XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode

I am using UNIX AIX Version 7.1 and 64-bit perl 5.22.0. `perl -V` gives:

```
Platform:
osname=aix, osvers=7.1.0.0, archname=aix
uname='aix 1 7 00f64d144c00 '
config_args='-des -Dprefix=/home/snemmal/perl'
hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
useithreads=undef, usemultiplicity=undef
use64bitint=undef, use64bitall=undef, uselongdouble=undef
usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
```

```
Compiler:
cc='cc -q32', ccflags ='-D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -        qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES',
optimize='-O',
cppflags='-D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN'
ccversion='9.0.0.19', gccversion='', gccosandvers=''
intsize=4, longsize=4, ptrsize=4, doublesize=8, byteorder=4321, doublekind=4
d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=8, longdblkind=0
ivtype='long', ivsize=4, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
alignbytes=8, prototype=define
```

```
Linker and Libraries:
ld='ld', ldflags =' -brtl -bdynamic -b32 -bmaxdata:0x80000000'
libpth=/lib /usr/lib /usr/ccs/lib
libs=-lpthread -lbind -lnsl -ldbm -ldl -lld -lm -lcrypt -lc
perllibs=-lpthread -lbind -lnsl -ldl -lld -lm -lcrypt -lc
libc=/lib/libc.a, so=a, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
gnulibc_version=''
```

```
Dynamic Linking:
dlsrc=dl_aix.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='  -bE:/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE/perl.exp'
cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='  -bhalt:4 -G -bI:$(PERL_INC)/perl.exp -bE:$(BASEEXT).exp -bnoentry -lc -lm '
```

I tried building like this:

1. Download and untar the .gz file from `search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.95/lib/Digest/SHA.pm`
2. `perl Makefile.PL` (ran successfully)
3. `make` (failed with "XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode")

Here is the full output of `make`:

> Skip blib/lib/Digest/SHA.pm (unchanged) Running Mkbootstrap for Digest::SHA () chmod 644 "SHA.bs" cc -q32 -c -I. -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES -O -DVERSION=\"5.95\" -DXS_VERSION=\"5.95\" "-I/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE" SHA.c
>
> rm -f blib/arch/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.so ld -bhalt:4 -G -bI:/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE/perl.exp -bE:SHA.exp -bnoentry -lc -lm SHA.o -o blib/arch/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.so ld: 0711-738 ERROR: Input file SHA.o: XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode. make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 8. Stop.

It looks like one of the object files from the module is in 32-bit mode, and my perl is in 64-bit mode. How can I install this module successfully?

Comment: CPAN distros don't contain binary files.

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: i had downloaded the .gz file from "http://search.cpan.org/~mshelor/Digest-SHA-5.95/lib/Digest/SHA.pm" untar and then using  commands  1.perl Makefile.PL (success) 2. make (failed with above error) 3.make test (yet to.. ) 4. make install (yet to..)

Comment: below is output of make (failed command)                                                     $  make
Skip blib/lib/Digest/SHA.pm (unchanged)
Running Mkbootstrap for Digest::SHA ()
        chmod 644 "SHA.bs"
        cc -q32 -c  -I.  -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES -O    -DVERSION=\"5.95\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"5.95\"  "-I/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE"   SHA.c
        (Part 1/2)

Comment: rm -f blib/arch/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.so
        ld  -bhalt:4 -G -bI:/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE/perl.exp -bE:SHA.exp -bnoentry -lc -lm  SHA.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.so
ld: 0711-738 ERROR: Input file SHA.o:
        XCOFF32 object files are not allowed in 64-bit mode.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 8.


Stop.
  (part 2/2)

Comment: @santhosh Please [edit] that info into your question and format it. It's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: `-q64` would be better for 64-bit than `-q32`

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy  but the above commands generated automatically when i just used make command. How can i edit that auto gen commands?

Comment: The output of `perl -V` (uppercase `V`) might be useful.

Comment: @OP: try `make CFLAGS=-q64 LDFLAGS=-q64`

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy just tried make CFLAGS=-q64 LDFLAGS=-q64    it is also resulting in same error.

Comment: Again, this is unreadable (and incomplete) and needs to be added to the question.

Comment: @ikegami  output of Perl -V is added to question.  Thanks! (only added compiler part as the output is huge)

Comment: Let me know what when you add the rest.

Comment: @santhosh The editor won't let you dump a bunch of code or text that looks like code without formatting it properly, because it's really hard to read. I've edited your question to show you how you can format things so they're readable. Now please add the rest of the `perl -V` output and **make it readable.**

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy again same error.

Comment: not sure how to deal with this  SHA.o in my 64 bit perl

Comment: restart with this: `perl Makefile.PL CC='xlc_r -q64'`

Comment: This also resulted in same error but one difference

Comment: with  perl Makefile.PL   
Output of make before error:

`cc -q32 -c  -I.  -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES -O    -DVERSION=\"5.95\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"5.95\"  "-I/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE"   SHA.c`

Comment: With perl Makefile.PL CC='xlc_r -q64'
output of make before error:

`xlc_r -q64 -c  -I.  -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ANSI_C_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -qmaxmem=-1 -qnoansialias -qlanglvl=extc99 -DUSE_NATIVE_DLOPEN -q32 -D_LARGE_FILES -O    -DVERSION=\"5.95\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"5.95\"  "-I/home/snemmal/perl/lib/5.22.0/aix/CORE"   SHA.c`

Comment: i want to add 2 points here 1) I had installed my own perl on this AIX machine as The exiating perl in this machine is of old version 2) the output of perl -V:ptrsize is ptrsize='4';  does it mean my perl is 32 bit??? if it is 32 bit why the error shows as 64-bit mode. (Please help i am new to perl)

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help.. Finally i got one solution... instead of using perl modules that are built with 'C' language, i now use built-in perl module... in this case it is "Digest::SHA::PurePerl module." Now there is no  overhead of 32-bit/64-bit...  (may be this solution is bit slow, but satisfied my hunger from last 2 days) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You try compile in 32bit "cc -q32 ", try to build with -q64 flag.